# Notation $S\twoheadrightarrow \,\,\,\stackrel{S}{}\!\!\unicode{x2215}_{\!\unicode{x202f}\sim} \hookrightarrow T$ in Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I am learning group theory now. My professor wrote down some notation that I was not able to understand. Can you tell me the meanings?

$$S\twoheadrightarrow 
\,\,\,\stackrel{S}{}\!\!\unicode{x2215}_{\!\unicode{x202f}\sim}
\hookrightarrow T$$

$$a\mapsto [a]\mapsto f(a)$$

Comment: The double arrow refers to a surjection (meaning that every element is realized as a value of the function), and the curved arrow refers to an injection (meaning that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$).  The third one is just a short hand for saying what the function takes a single element to.   Thus, if $f(x)=x^2$, we might write $2\mapsto 2^2$ or even $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: And the $\mapsto$ refers to an element of a set being mapped (by a function or (homo)morphism), to a specific element. So the line before and attached to the arrow denotes that this is at the level of elements of sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\twoheadrightarrow$ typically denotes surjection:  so $f: A \twoheadrightarrow B$ means that $f$ is onto.

Dually, $\hookrightarrow$ indiciates injection.  Sometimes it is used in a stricter sense to denote an honest inclusion of a subset.  So if $A \subseteq B$ one may write $i: A \hookrightarrow B$ for the inclusion map $i(a)=a$.

$\mapsto$ indicates the action of a function on an element of the domain.  So if $f: A \to B$ does $f(w)=z$, one may write $f: w \mapsto z$.

Also:  this notation is not specific to group theory, but applies to functions between sets generally.

Comment: While the first one denotes surjection, the second one typically denotes some kind of inclusion map in my experience.

Comment: @Jakobian  I've seen it both ways plenty of times, but I will edit my answer to incorporate this.